# What is ((->) t ) in haskell?

Tags: haskell, notation

I am doing [20 intermediate Haskell exercises](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/20-intermediate-haskell-exercises/).

After finishing first 2 exercise there is this strange thing.

I would like to know what is `((->) t)`?

```
-- Exercise 3
-- Relative Difficulty: 5
instance Fluffy ((->) t) where
  furry = error "todo"
```

Thanks! :-)

Comment: If you want, you can just think of it as `instance Fluffy (t ->) where`, except operator sections are syntactically illegal in this case.

Answer (score 4):

`(->)` is the type constructor for functions which has kind `* -> * -> *` so it requires two type parameters - the input and result type of the function. `((->) t` is a partial application of this constructor so it is functions with an argument type of `t` i.e. (t -> a) for some type `a`.

If you substitute that into the type of the `furry` function you get:

```
furry :: (a -> b) -> (t -> a) -> (t -> b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read prefix `(->) t a` as infix `t -> a`.

If we have

```
instance Fluffy Maybe where
```

for `Maybe a` type (and `* -> *` kind), then

```
instance Fluffy ((->) t) where
```

is for `(->) t a == t -> a` type (and `* -> *` kind) - for any function with 1 argument